# How to compute the sum of group by and return for a condition in psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Table 1

```
Name Quantity     Type     Value   Date
Car    1            B         10,000  time-stamp1
Car    2            S          10,000  time-stamp2
Bus    1            B          10,000  time-stamp3
```

So, that's my table structure. I want my sql query to group the results based on name and only return me the result where Quantity of type S > Quantity of type B.
Though I'm able to do a group by, I'm not sure how to do a Sum of the Group By and only return for the particular condition Quantity of type S > Quantity of type B.

Comment: Have you tried adding `WHERE "Quantity-S" > "Quantity-B"` before your `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: @NickBarnes I've edited the question. Would you mind checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do it in two steps.
First calculate quantities for S and B using sum with CASE expressions:

```
SELECT name,
       sum( CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END ) As q_b,
       sum( CASE WHEN Type = 'S' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END ) As q_s,
       sum( Quantity ) As q
FROM Table1
GROUP BY name
;
```

then select only requred rows from the result of the above query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
   SELECT name,
          sum( CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END ) As q_b,
          sum( CASE WHEN Type = 'S' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END ) As q_s,
          sum( Quantity ) As q
   FROM Table1
   GROUP BY name
) s
WHERE q_s > q_b
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f394f/2

Comment: No need for a subquery here, you can use a `HAVING` clause to put `WHERE` constraints on aggregate results. Though you can't refer to `q_s` and `q_b`; you need need to repeat the entire aggregate expression (i.e. `HAVING sum(CASE WHEN Type = 'S' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END) > sum(CASE WHEN Type = 'B' THEN Quantity ELSE 0 END)`).